# Search for movies with same title using Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, iteration, binary-search-tree

I have a project I am working on that involves making a database of movies. I have a Movie object and my problem is that I am having trouble printing out Movies that have the same title. Currently only one of the movies is being printed out. I am sure my search function in my `BinarySearchTree` class is working because it finds it correctly, I think it is stopping once the search condition is met and it doesn't look for any other possible movies with the same title. I think to solve this I just need to implement a `loop` that will print out each movie as as it is found when traversing the BinarySearchTree.

Here is my search function in `BinarySearchTree`:

```
public Node search( Movie m ){
    if ( root == null ){
        System.out.println("No items to search.");
        return null;
    }else{
        return search( m, root );
    }
}
private Node search( Movie m, Node n){
    if ( m.compareTo( n.getData() ) == 0 ){
        if(n.getLeft() != null){//Go left to continue searching
           Node node = search(m, n.getLeft());
           if(node != null)
              return node;
        }
        return n;
    }else{
        if ( n.getRight() == null ){
            System.out.println("Item not found.");
            return null;
        }else{
            return search(m, n.getRight());
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation in my Main that currently only prints out only one of the movies with the same title (the first one it comes across). I need a loop I think or some way to keep iterating through the tree.

```
public static BinarySearchTree findByTitle( BinarySearchTree tree ){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the title of the movie: ");
    Movie temp = new Movie( input.nextLine() );

    Node leftMost = tree.search(temp);
    if( leftMost != null ){
           while(leftMost != null && temp.compareTo( leftMost.getData() ) == 0){
                System.out.println(leftMost.getData());
                leftMost = leftMost.getRight();
           }
    }
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: Please tell us more about `other possible movies with the same title`? So they need to be a perfect matches, or just have same prefix or smt else?

Comment: @PhamTrung Yes, they must have same title only, for example Iets say I have 3 movies titled 'Star Wars'. Currently, only one 'Star Wars' would be printed out. The movies with same title have other information such as different actors or year released which makes them different.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can get the left most entry by modifying the search function:

```
private Node search( Movie m, Node n){
    if ( m.compareTo( n.getData() ) == 0 ){
        if(n.getLeft() != null){//Go left to continue searching
           Node node = search(m, n.getLeft());
           if(node != null)
              return node;
        }
        return n;
    }
    if ( m.compareTo( n.getData() ) < 0 ){
        if( n.getLeft() == null){
            System.out.println("Item not found.");
            return null;
        }else{
            return search(m, n.getLeft());
        }
    }else{
        if ( n.getRight() == null ){
            System.out.println("Item not found.");
        return null;
    }else{
        return search(m, n.getRight());
    }
}
```

After getting the left most node, just keep getting to the right until the movie's title is not equals.

```
Node leftMost = search(m);
if(leftMost != null){
   while(leftMost != null && m.compareTo(leftMost.getData()) == 0){
        System.out.println(leftMost.getData());
        leftMost = leftMost.getRight();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated my post with your suggestions. Unfortunately, now it seems that it is not finding the movies that are on the right side of the tree. Im not sure if I need to modify the the search function for the right now?

Comment: @JCCS I think you accidentally removed the part when `m.compareTo( n.getData() ) < 0` in search function, so put it back and it will solve your problem :)

Comment: @JCCS  sorry for spam, but can you describe more about the data structure you are using? you mentioned this is a tree?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be a Binary Search Tree.

Comment: @JCCS hmm, if this is a binary search tree, so go left, go right is not enough, because we need to print descendant node, not just right or left node,... actually, you can take a look at [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), which is built-in BST for java, and it supports all of your need :) (just try to avoid reinventing the wheel)

Comment: Yes, after making all the changes, i am still left with the same issue :(. Also, for this assignment it is required I use my own created BST class.